# Open Erp - access rights or rules

Tags: openerp

In OpenErp, how to restrict Team leads/managers of other dept suppose Developer from approving leave requests of an employee(from other dept(testing)) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set access rule for that,

```
Go to Settings -> Security -> Record Rules

Model = hr.holidays, Read = True, Write = True

['|',('employee_id.department_id','=',False),('employee_id.department_id','=',user.department_id.id)]
```

And set groups for which you want to set this rule. It will allows groups member to set leave request of an employees which are belongs to his department or does not belongs to any departments.